# City auto Fill when zip code entered

Tags: magento2.3

How to auto fill or validate city based on zip code in magento 2.3.6 address field of my account page and checkout page

Answer (score 0):

you can follow this link
[Extention Attributes in payload return as null in backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/228645/extention-attributes-in-payload-return-as-null-in-backend)

to get shipping data when you click on next button, and based on that you can through error

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: if this answer is helpfull for you than accept this answer, so it will help for other